# a simple python code debugging

Tags: python-3.x

I want to run this code using the input n=12. Why is this generating errors?

```
def rec(n):
    if n<4:
        return n
    temp=n//12
    temp=13*temp
    sum=rec(temp)
    if(sum<=n):
        return n
    return sum

n=10
n=int(input())
print(rec(n))
```

Comment: Why are *what* errors generate?

Answer (score 0):

In order for recursion to work, you need to make progress towards termination (where a recursive call does *not* get made).  When n>=12, temp is a value larger than 12, and thus the recursion will never terminate (well, at least until you reach Python's recursion depth limit).

So either your algorithm is bad, or its implementation is.